# How to merge dataframe rows with different values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe containing data of requests made by users:

```
user_id    status
1          IN_ANALYSIS
1          APPROVED
1          DISAPPROVED
2          IN_ANALYSIS
2          IN_ANALYSIS
3          APPROVED
3          APPROVED
3          CONTRACTED
```

I'd like to merge the dataframe rows by the `user_id` so if a user has at least one request APPROVED or CONTRACTED the resulting status must be APPROVED, otherwise it must be DISAPPROVED. For instance, for the data above, the resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
user_id    status
1          APPROVED
2          DISAPPROVED
3          APPROVED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up parameters defined by OP

```
a_status = ['APPROVED', 'CONTRACTED']
mapping = {True: 'APPROVED', False: 'DISAPPROVED'}
```

Use `isin`, `groupby`, and `map`

```
df.status.isin(a_status).groupby(df.user_id).any().map(mapping).reset_index()

   user_id       status
0        1     APPROVED
1        2  DISAPPROVED
2        3     APPROVED
```

**Explanation**

- Evaluate truthiness of each row.
- Use `groupby` and `any` to see if any satisfy the truth condition.
- Map truth back to `APPROVED`/`DISAPPROVED`

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = df.groupby('user_id')['status'].apply(list)\
        .apply(lambda x: 'APPROVED' if any(i in x for i in ['APPROVED', 'CONTRACTED']) else 'DISAPPROVED')\
        .reset_index()

#    user_id       status
# 0        1     APPROVED
# 1        2  DISAPPROVED
# 2        3     APPROVED
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by the user, then aggregate a list of their outcomes. Then define a function to check on the status, based on some custom logic you create. Finally, use the map function to apply the logic to the column and create a new_col, which you could then use as you see fit. Less elegant than a one liner, but perhaps more interpretable.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df = df.groupby('user_id')['status'].apply(lambda x: "%s" % ', '.join(x).split()).reset_index()

def logic(row):
    if 'APPROVED' in row or 'CONTRACTED' in row:
        return 'APPROVED'
    else:
        return 'DISAPPROVED'

df['new_col'] = df.status.map(logic)
df.head()

  user_id                                        status      new_col
0        1  ['IN_ANALYSIS,', 'APPROVED,', 'DISAPPROVED']     APPROVED
1        2               ['IN_ANALYSIS,', 'IN_ANALYSIS']  DISAPPROVED
2        3      ['APPROVED,', 'APPROVED,', 'CONTRACTED']     APPROVED
```